Can we take the carried-over passive losses from 2023 this year?
We've had a short-term rental property the last few years.   We've been able to take the passive losses on it using the "Special Allowance for Rental Real Estate" on Form 8582.     However, coming into 2024, we have a carry-over of about $5000 of disallowed losses from 2023 (because they exceeded the $25,000 cap).
This year we are converting the property to a second home.  Can we take the carried-over passive losses from 2023 this year (or does that require passive income to offset it against) ?
If "yes", how can we do it ?  We have not rented it at all during 2024, so there is no Schedule E.  I don't think you can file Form 8582 without a Schedule E.
